# ngIf not working Angular 7 After first time

Tags: angular, typescript

here is HTML code

```
<form class="k-form-inline" [formGroup]="catalogForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" (keyup.enter)="onSubmit()">
     <button class="k-button k-primary" style="width:100px" [disabled]="loading" style="margin-right:15px" >
              <span class="k-icon k-i-zoom" style="padding-right: 20px"> </span>Search
     </button>
     <span *ngIf="loading" class="k-icon k-i-loading" style="font-size: 16px; padding-left:10px"></span>
</form>
```

on component

```
public loading : boolean = false;

onSubmit() {
    this.loading = true;
     this.Service.subscribe(res => {this.loading = false;})
}
```

**EDIT** : here is service code.

```
export class ProductService  extends BehaviorSubject<GridDataResult>{

constructor(private http: HttpClient) 
  { super(null); }

protected fetch(state: any, searchForm: ProductCatalogSearch,CustomerGroupCode : string): Observable<GridDataResult> {
    searchForm.CustomerGroupCode = CustomerGroupCode;
    return this.http
      .post<any>(this.rootURL + '/product/catalogsearch', searchForm)
      .pipe(
        map(response => (<GridDataResult>{
          data: response,
          total: (response as any[]).length
        }))
      );
  }

  public query(state: any, searchForm: ProductCatalogSearch, CustomerGroupCode: string): void {
    this.fetch(state, searchForm,CustomerGroupCode)
      .subscribe(x => super.next(x));
  }
}
```

This works perfectly when i click button first time after loading/refreshing. after that it stops working in subsequent clicks. submit is working fine in any click, some reason the 'loading' variable is not changing.

Am i missing anything?

Comment: What is `Service`?

Comment: its my service class which returns the data

Comment: Do you think it would be a good idea to add that implementation in your question as well? There could be something wrong with that implementation.

Comment: i am not seeing any error over there, but here is the service code for your reference.

Comment: @Dips console the `loading` after you get response.

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting `this.loading` to `false` if your call returns error:

```
onSubmit() {
  this.loading = true;
  this.Service.subscribe(res => {
    this.loading = false;
  }, error => {
    this.loading = false;
  });
}
```

Comment: i am not getting any error, and i have code over there to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing the lifecycle hook AfterViewChecked along with detectChanges. This should help angular detect the loading variable changes.

```
import { AfterViewChecked, ChangeDetectorRef, Component } from '@angular/core';
...
constructor(private cdref: ChangeDetectorRef)
...
ngAfterViewChecked(): void { this.cdref.detectChanges(); }
```

Comment: i just tried it. it didn't work. OnSubmit i am making loading=true, first time it is working, but second time OnSubmit it is not taking an effect on template.